# 100% usage for 11G/40G, how is it possible?

Tags: linux, centos6, godaddy, disk-space-utilization

How is it possible to have the stats below: 11G used over 40G Size and no more space available. Now I cannot send my e-mail because I receive: **An error occurred while sending mail. The mail server responded:  Error while writing spool file. Please check the message and try again.**

```
root@ip-a-b-c-d [~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs              40G   11G     0 100% /
none                  512M  4.0K  512M   1% /dev
```

Can you help me solve this issue ?

```
root@ip-a-b-c-d [~]# df -ih
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs               8.6M    420K    8.2M    5% /
none                    128K      95    128K    1% /dev

root@ip-a-b-c-d [~]# lsof +L1
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NLINK    NODE NAME
dovecot   21906     root  111u   REG   0,30        0     0  758435 (deleted) /var/run/dovecot/login-master-notifyd227fbaeb43252e5
dovecot   21906     root  128u   REG   0,30        0     0  758440 (deleted) /var/run/dovecot/login-master-notifyc9b5bae7b2edcb9e
dovecot   21906     root  131u   REG   0,30        0     0  758442 (deleted) /var/run/dovecot/login-master-notify7fc65ebf8eeeaa52
pop3-logi 21914 dovenull    4u   REG   0,30        0     0  758435 (deleted) /var/run/dovecot/login-master-notifyd227fbaeb43252e5
imap-logi 21915 dovenull    4u   REG   0,30        0     0  758442 (deleted) /var/run/dovecot/login-master-notify7fc65ebf8eeeaa52
pop3-logi 21919 dovenull    4u   REG   0,30        0     0  758435 (deleted) /var/run/dovecot/login-master-notifyd227fbaeb43252e5
imap-logi 21920 dovenull    4u   REG   0,30        0     0  758442 (deleted) /var/run/dovecot/login-master-notify7fc65ebf8eeeaa52
httpd     22365     root   44w   REG   0,30        0     0 1597059 (deleted) /usr/local/apache/logs/ssl_mutex
httpd     22373   nobody   44w   REG   0,30        0     0 1597059 (deleted) /usr/local/apache/logs/ssl_mutex
httpd     22374   nobody   44w   REG   0,30        0     0 1597059 (deleted) /usr/local/apache/logs/ssl_mutex
httpd     22375   nobody   44w   REG   0,30        0     0 1597059 (deleted) /usr/local/apache/logs/ssl_mutex
httpd     22376   nobody   44w   REG   0,30        0     0 1597059 (deleted) /usr/local/apache/logs/ssl_mutex
httpd     22377   nobody   44w   REG   0,30        0     0 1597059 (deleted) /usr/local/apache/logs/ssl_mutex
httpd     24097   nobody   44w   REG   0,30        0     0 1597059 (deleted) /usr/local/apache/logs/ssl_mutex
mysqld    25732    mysql    4u   REG   0,30        0     0  693076 (deleted) /tmp/ibaGzgNW
mysqld    25732    mysql    5u   REG   0,30        0     0  693077 (deleted) /tmp/ibkJLbId
mysqld    25732    mysql    6u   REG   0,30        0     0  693078 (deleted) /tmp/ib0oe7Cu
mysqld    25732    mysql    7u   REG   0,30        0     0  693079 (deleted) /tmp/ibKOvzu2
mysqld    25732    mysql   11u   REG   0,30        0     0  694204 (deleted) /tmp/ibKKlSrj
```

Comment: There are open deleted files, which can be released by restarting the relevant services, but in this instance it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: /dev/vzfs would be Virtuozzo File System, I assume. I wonder if the underlying storage is over-committed, or something like that. This might be one for your hosting provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if you delete large files that a process has open (eg, large log files are a common example). If the application doesn't reopen the files, the old file handle sticks around and the space cannot be reclaimed.

If you know which file you deleted and which process owns them, you could try restarting that process. Or, restart your server and the space should get freed after that

Comment: In this case, restart mysql.